# Fix columns indentation with python

Tags: python, awk

There is a file format called `.xyz` that helps visualizing molecular bonds. Basically the format asks for a specific pattern:

At the first line there must be the number of atoms, which in my case is 30. 
After that there should be the data where the first line is the name of the atom, in my case they are all carbon. The second line is the x information and the third line is the y information and the last line is the z information which are all 0 in my case. Indentation should be correct so that all of the corresponding lines should start at the same place. So something like this:

```
30
C x1 y1 z1 
C x2 y2 z2
...
...
...
```

and not:

```
30 
C x1 y1 z1
C   x2 y2  z2
```

since this is the wrong indentation.

My generated data is stored like this in a `.txt` file:

```
C       2.99996     7.31001e-05     0
C       2.93478     0.623697        0
C       2.74092     1.22011     0
C       2.42702     1.76343     0
C       2.0079      2.22961     0
C       1.50006     2.59812     0
C       0.927076        2.8532      0
C       0.313848        2.98349     0
C       -0.313623       2.9837      0
C       -0.927229       2.85319     0
C       -1.5003     2.5981      0
C       -2.00732        2.22951     0
C       -2.42686        1.76331     0
C       -2.74119        1.22029     0
C       -2.93437        0.623802        0
C       -2.99992        -5.5509e-05     0
C       -2.93416        -0.623574       0
C       -2.7409     -1.22022        0
C       -2.42726        -1.7634     0
C       -2.00723        -2.22941        0
C       -1.49985        -2.59809        0
C       -0.92683        -2.85314        0
C       -0.313899       -2.98358        0
C       0.31363     -2.98356        0
C       0.927096        -2.85308        0
C       1.50005     -2.59792        0
C       2.00734     -2.22953        0
C       2.4273      -1.76339        0
C       2.74031     -1.22035        0
C       2.93441     -0.623647       0
```

I want to correct the indentation of this by making all of the lines start from the same point. I tried to do this with AWK to no avail. So I turned to Python. So far I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
text_file = open("output.txt","r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
myfile = open("output.xyz","w")
for line in lines:
    atom, x, y, z = line.split()
    x, y, z = map(float(x,y,z))
    myfile.write("{}\t {}\t {}\t {}\t".format(atom,x,y,z))
myfile.close()
text_file.close()
```

but I don't know currently as to how indentation can be added into this.

**tl;dr:** I have a data file in .`txt`, I want to change it into `.xyz` that's been specified but I am running into problems with indentation.

Comment: Are you just looking for fixed width columns (i.e. make your data look pretty) or do you require the columns to be separated by a tab character (because that's how a program is expecting the format)? The two requirements are quite different.

Comment: The requirement is that all the separate lines should start from the exact same point whether they are tab separated or just white space between them doesn't matter. I could even lose some significant points for getting them start from the same point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I misinterpreted your requirement...

To achieve a fixed width output using awk, you could use `printf` with a format string like this:

```
$ awk '{printf "%-4s%12.6f%12.6f%5d\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' data.txt 
C       2.999960    0.000073    0
C       2.934780    0.623697    0
C       2.740920    1.220110    0
C       2.427020    1.763430    0
C       2.007900    2.229610    0
C       1.500060    2.598120    0
C       0.927076    2.853200    0
C       0.313848    2.983490    0
C      -0.313623    2.983700    0
# etc.
```

Numbers after the `%` specify the width of the field. A negative number means that the output should be left aligned (as in the first column). I have specified 6 decimal places for the floating point numbers.

---

#### Original answer, in case it is useful:

To ensure that there is a tab character between each of the columns of your input, you could use this awk script:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\t" data.txt > output.xyz
```

`$1=$1` just forces awk to touch each line, which makes sure that the new Output Field Separator (`OFS`) is applied.

awk scripts are built up from a series of `condition { action }`. If no condition is supplied, the action is performed for every line. If a condition but no action is supplied, the default action is to print the line. `1` is a condition that always evaluates to true, so awk prints the line.

Note that even though the columns are all tab-separated, they are still not lined up because the content of each column is of a variable length.

Comment: Thank you. What is the 1 at the end of the curly parenthesis for as in '{$1=$1}1' ? @Tensibai: Yes that is indeed the case, but this seems like a good check to ensure that there is a tab space between the inputs.

Comment: I have added to my answer.

Comment: @ozdm I have updated my answer to show how you can produce fixed width output instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works, but the problem is that I need to write this in a so-called .xyz file and I am not entirely sure if it can be doable with awk. I'll give it a try now in any case.

Comment: @ozdm To write the output of the script to a file, you just need to do `awk 'script' input_file > output_file.xyz`. Just so you know, a lot of programs don't care about having all of the columns lined up in a fixed width format (this is more of a human readability issue), so I would be surprised if your original file was not recognised by the program you are using. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your data has already been ill formatted and converted to string. To correctly allign the numeric and non-numeric data, you need to parse the individual fields to respective data types (possibly using duck-typing) before formating using `str.format`

```
for line in st.splitlines():
    def convert(st):
        try:
            return int(st)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        try:
            return float(st)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return st
    print "{:8}{:12.5f}{:12.5f}{:5d}".format(*map(convert,line.split()))


C            2.99996     0.00007    0
C            2.93478     0.62370    0
C            2.74092     1.22011    0
C            2.42702     1.76343    0
C            2.00790     2.22961    0
C            1.50006     2.59812    0
C            0.92708     2.85320    0
C            0.31385     2.98349    0
C           -0.31362     2.98370    0
C           -0.92723     2.85319    0
```

Comment: Why would the data type of each column matter? This would only serve to reduce the number of significant figures in the output.

Comment: @TomFenech: The reason it would matter is, if the data type is not considered, the data would be aligned as strings, which would mean all of them would be left aligned and you would see an unaligned decimal point orientation

Comment: You are spot on! I didn't even notice that I had the error of changing numeric values into string. I'll try to understand the syntax, since I'm quite a beginner in python and will try to implement it into my code.

Comment: Why not just right-align the strings then? There is absolutely no need to convert to float and back to string in order to provide a fixed format output.

Comment: @TomFenech: All the data do not have the same precision, so either you need to pad extra zeros or truncate each field, which would make it  harder.

Comment: OK, I see your point. I guess the "right" answer depends on whether the user is trying to make a machine-readable format (such as tab-separated columns) or a human-readable one (such as fixed width).

Comment: @TomFenech: The original O/P is already machine readable, and if it was not, the above approach would not have been able to convert it to human readable.

Comment: I am actually having a hard time trying to understand the syntax. Care to explain it a bit in somewhat more detail, so that I could implement? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using this: `awk '{printf "%s\t%10f\t%10f\t%i\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' atoms`

give this output:

```
C         2.999960        0.000073      0
C         2.934780        0.623697      0
C         2.740920        1.220110      0
C         2.427020        1.763430      0
C         2.007900        2.229610      0
C         1.500060        2.598120      0
C         0.927076        2.853200      0
C         0.313848        2.983490      0
C        -0.313623        2.983700      0
C        -0.927229        2.853190      0
C        -1.500300        2.598100      0
C        -2.007320        2.229510      0
C        -2.426860        1.763310      0
C        -2.741190        1.220290      0
C        -2.934370        0.623802      0
C        -2.999920       -0.000056      0
C        -2.934160       -0.623574      0
C        -2.740900       -1.220220      0
C        -2.427260       -1.763400      0
C        -2.007230       -2.229410      0
C        -1.499850       -2.598090      0
C        -0.926830       -2.853140      0
C        -0.313899       -2.983580      0
C         0.313630       -2.983560      0
C         0.927096       -2.853080      0
C         1.500050       -2.597920      0
C         2.007340       -2.229530      0
C         2.427300       -1.763390      0
C         2.740310       -1.220350      0
C         2.934410       -0.623647      0
```

Is it what you're meaning or did I misunderstood ?

Edit for side note: I used tabs `\t` for separation, a space could do too and I limited the output to a precision of 10, I didn't verify your input lenght

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to print values with consistent padding. For your case, you might write lines like this to the file:

```
>>> '%-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s\n' % ('C', '2.99996', '7.31001e-05', '0')
'C            2.99996      7.31001e-05  0           '
```

"%-12s" means "take the str() of the value and make it take up at least 12 characters left-justified.